# What is PCRE-compatible syntax? And is C# PCRE-compatible?

Tags: c#, regex

What is PCRE-compatible syntax? And is C# PCRE-compatible?
From wikipedia I found this:

> Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) is a regular expression C
>   library inspired by the regular expression capabilities in the Perl
>   programming language, written by Philip Hazel, starting in summer
>   1997. PCRE's syntax is much more powerful and flexible than either of the POSIX regular expression flavors and many classic regular
>   expression libraries. The name is misleading, because PCRE and Perl
>   each have capabilities not shared by the other.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: And how would you expect C# (which isn't a regular expression syntax) to be compatible with PCRE? Do you mean "Is the regular expression syntax used by .NET's `Regex` class compatible with PCRE?" perhaps?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you're right. I don't know any think about PCRE up to now.

Comment: I come to this question because of this issue in `Regex101`: https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/124

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C# regexes share some syntax with PCRE regexes. Most of the features overlap but both libraries keep their own specifics:

A couple examples:

**PCRE**

- Supports recursion
- Supports backtrack control verbs
- Supports constructs like `(?(DEFINE) ... )`
- Supports more options
- Offers a DFA parsing mode
- Supports partial matches
- Supports `\K`
- Supports `X++` shorthand syntax (equivalent of `(?>X+)`)

**.NET**

- Supports capture stacks and duplicate named groups
- Supports balancing groups
- Supports variable length lookbehind

This list is not exhaustive. You can compare both flavours on [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html) and the sibling pages.

Given the differences, I wanted to be able to use PCRE regexes from .NET and recently started [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net), which is a wrapper project. It's not finished yet but is starting to be usable.

Comment: As a long term user of the old PCRE wrapper for .NET I was glad to find the one you've been working on (compatible with 4.5.2 which the old one isn't) and doubly glad to find it's equally fast, 3 years ago I was doing a lot of regex processing and switched to PCRE when I realised how appallingly slow native C# regex processing is. Recent example -  100 files through approx 90 regex rules, C# - 190s, PCRE - 4s......

Comment: @Simon nice, thanks for the feedback! :) though it heavily depends on the regex involved, I haven't spent enough time on benchmarking yet, but some patterns are definitely faster in .NET.

Comment: Mine are mainly zero width lookahead types, i.e. (?=.*?words)(?=.*?order)(?=.*?in)(?=.*?any). The issue (kind of!) I have now is that I'm processing 3K documents already in memory and old C# had my CPU at 100% but with PCRE it wont go over about 25%, there's no other activity disk etc. and I'm running the 3K in a parallel foreach against the 90 regexes, even adding a load of debug output only pushed the CPU to 45%! Assuming I've hit some physical CPU reading RAM limit that isn't so easy to monitor, assume there is nothing thread limiting in PCRE?

Comment: @Simon nope, PCRE and PCRE.NET are fully thread-safe. Looks like it's time to use a profiler on your code, it's the only way to know where the bottleneck comes from. Though in your case I think you'd be better off avoiding regexes altogether and using `String.Contains` or maybe you should consider something like Lucene.NET. Also, I hope this regex starts with `^` :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the threading. Profiler is my next task, I don't use ^ as always run these with Match so assumed (naively?) that covered the start anchoring. A colleague mentioned String.Contains but given these regexs rarely register double digit ElapsedTicks would 4 String.Contains vs. say the previous regex really be faster or is it the short circuiting that helps although I wonder if the regex would do the same if the first word isn't found.

Comment: @Simon, no, `Match` will try to find a match at any starting position, so you should anchor your pattern either with `^`, `\A` or `PcreOptions.Anchored`. For performance you should also make sure you're using `PcreOptions.Compiled` and `PcreMatchOptions.NoUtfCheck` (don't confuse with `PcreOptions.NoUtfCheck`) if you can ensure your input is a valid Unicode string. And the only way to be sure whether `String.Contains` is faster or not is, well... to measure both approaches with your data ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124016/discussion-between-simon-and-lucas-trzesniewski).