# Regex - MARK to see which capture group was matched

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pcre

I'm writing a small tokenizer in C#.

In the PCRE Regex specification there's the neat `MARK` keyword:
https://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC23

This is how it works:

https://3v4l.org/ErCrp

```
<?php

$string = 'bar';
$matches = [];

preg_match('~(?|foo(*:1)
               |bar(*:2)
               |baz(*:3))~x', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

//> array(2) { 
//>     [0]=> string(3) "bar" 
//>     ["MARK"]=> string(1) "2" 
//> }
```

As you can see, the `MARK` parameter in the result set allows you to see which branch of the regular expression was actually matched. Unfortunately, the `MARK` keyword is not supported in .NETs Regex framework. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
var pattern = @"(
    (?<foo>foo)
    |(?<bar>bar)
    |(?<baz>baz)
)";

var regexOptions = RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
var regex = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
var matches = regex.Matches("bar");

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    int? mark = null;

    if (match.Groups["foo"].Success)
    {
        mark = 1;
    }
    else if (match.Groups["bar"].Success)
    {
        mark = 2;
    }
    else if (match.Groups["baz"].Success)
    {
        mark = 3;
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to reconstruct the entire regular expression to see which capture group was actually matched.

This seems backwards. Is there a better way I can do the same thing?

The reason I need this is because in a tokenizer I don't just need to know if the syntax is valid but also which token type the matched token actually is.

Comment: What about named capturing groups?

Comment: Put the possible tokens in a dictionary and loop over them. Then try to match right at the start of the string and see which one was matched - here, grab the token name, consume the string and break the loop.

Comment: If you need to work out which token was matched, why not just read the value of the outer group?

Comment: @revo My current solution does use named capture groups ;)

Comment: @Rawling I don't completely understand your comment. Of course I have the string value of the matched tokens but I'd still need to figure out what type that token has. Let's say I'm matching 20 different keywords, I don't want to do 20 if statements for that.

Comment: Aah yes I didn't go through entire question. So your problem is with multiple if statements. With `MARK` you have if statements too.

Comment: @revo No, with MARK you have no if statements because I could pass the correct token type (which is an enum) to the MARK value. This way I'd simply extract the MARK value.

Comment: May you show me this *I could pass the correct token type (which is an enum) to the MARK value*? I didn't get it.

Comment: If you have an enum you can just use `Enum.Parse` to turn the string you have into the enum value.

Comment: @Rawling A string literal token token `"Foo"` is not a single value. There can be a unlimited number of string literals. This is nothing `Enum.Parse` can do for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use the `MARK` info or want to use PCRE regexes from .NET in general, take a look at [PCRE.NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net), which is a .NET wrapper (available via NuGet) for the PCRE library. It offers a lot of PCRE's features for use from .NET, including Mark retrieval.

Here is a short example:

```
using PCRE;
using System.Linq;
namespace PCREdNET
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var marks = PcreRegex.Matches("bar", "(?|foo(*:1)|bar(*:2)|baz(*:3))")
                       .Select(m => m.Mark)
                       .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some context on C#'s PCRE-compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504537/8291949

Comment: Well, I'm not insisting on using `MARK``, I'm just wondering if there's a similar solution that does not require reconstructing the branches of the regular expression itself.

The library looks interesting!