# PowerShell match a pattern within a string

Tags: string, powershell

Quite a stupid question but I can't figure out how to do this....

I get the OS name from `Get-ADComputer`, lets say: "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard".

I am trying to just select the Year within the Build, eg:

```
"Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard" > 2012
"Windows Server 2019" > 2019
"Windows Server 2008" > 2008
"Windows Server 2008 R2" > 2008
```

Quite ignorant on Regex...how could I do it?.

Also, is there a good tutorial on Regex for Powershell you can refer me to?

Comment: `"Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard" -match '\d{4}'`

Comment: https://regexr.com/ should work for any language. u can also test ur regex there

Comment: After the `match` statement as Vivek suggested, ur result should be in `$Matches.Values`

Comment: @Sid https://regexr.com only officially supports Javascript and PCRE regex. That said, .NET regex is very close to PCRE, and I have yet to find a PCRE expression that doesn't work in the .NET engine. Here is a rough list of engine specific features that don't overlap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504263/what-is-pcre-compatible-syntax-and-is-c-sharp-pcre-compatible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match on the string with the following pattern like so:

```
$year = if( "Windows Server 2019" -match '\d{4}' ){
  $matches[0]
}
```

This works by using the `-match` operator to check that a match against a pattern (regex) is found. If the match is found (`-match` returns `$True` or `$False`), you can then use the automatic `$matches` array to find what value matches the pattern. `$matches[0]` will contain the matched value, any additional elements would signify matching capturing groups as part of more complex expressions.

As for the expression itself, `\d` indicates to match on a numeric character and the `{4}` is a quantifier, stating that we want to match on ***exactly 4*** of the preceeding character or token.

Of course, if `-match` returned `$False` above, then `$year` would not be set with a value.

> Note that the `-match` operator does not support global matching if you ever needed to find ***all*** occurrences of a pattern in a string.

### But what if I need to match on all occurrences of a pattern in a string?

Your use case above doesn't call for this, but if we do need a global matching option, we can use the `[Regex]::Matches` method here, which performs a global pattern match on the input string:

```
$myString = "2019 2018 a clockwork orangutan 2017 2016"
[Regex]::Matches( $myString, '\d{4}' ).Value # => 2019
                                             #    2018
                                             #    2017
                                             #    2016
```

`[Regex]::Matches` returns an array of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8) objects. The `Value` property contains the actual string that matches the pattern, but you can also look at other properties of this object to learn more information as well, such as the which index in the string the pattern match was found in, for example.

### A good regex resource

As for "a good tutorial" on regex, I can't recommend one, but I do make use of https://regexr.com/ when writing and testing regular expressions. It doesn't support .NET regex, but you can change the mode to PCRE which works very closely to how .NET regex works. As you write your expressions, it will break your expression down and explain what each character (or special token) means. There is also a decent reference you can use as well.